# Ruby on Rails | How to apply validation on rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activeadmin

I am adding the promo code option for my application. I want to apply validation on the form that will match the entered promo code by the user to the promo code that has been already there in the admin dashboard (Activeadmin is used for admin dashboard).

I have tried a few options but nothing works. Examples that I have tried -

```
def validate_promo_code
  if promo_code.present? and (!promo_code.match(EngineName::PromoCode.promo_code))
    errors.add :promo_code, "must be a valid promo code"
  end
end
```

```
def validate_promo_code
 if promo_code.present? and (promo_code != EngineName::PromoCode.where(promo_code: promo_code))
   errors.add :promo_code, "must be valid promo code"
   return;
 end
end
```

Does anyone has any idea how to achieve this? Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if someone is still looking for the solution, try this one -

```
def validate_promo_code
      existing_code = EngineName::PromoCode.where(promo_code: promo_code)
        if promo_code.present? and !(existing_code.present?)
          errors.add :promo_code, "must be valid promo code"
        end
    end
```

This solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your activerecord model aware of the validation  using the `validate` dsl statement. Does this work?

```
validate :ensure_valid_promo_code

def ensure_valid_promo_code
  if promo_code.present? && (!promo_code.match(EngineName::PromoCode.promo_code))
    errors.add :promo_code, "must be a valid promo code"
  end
end
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work.

Comment: Too bad. What happens when you comment the ```if```, so that the errors is always added no matter what, does it appear in the form? Perhaps extend your answer with the code from the ```form do``` block in your activadmin register block.